# Which PostgreSQL Package to Install

Tags: postgresql

We have the following requirements. Could anyone suggest which PostgreSQL package to choose?

1. Server supporting multiple connections on the same port
2. Trigger
3. GUI to interact with the server
4. Features to support back up & restore database
5. Ability to connect to a remote postgreSQL server

We would require it for both Windows 7 & OS X El Capitan

UPDATE:
The below link contains multiple links to download PostgreSQL. As we can not download all of them & try out, require someone's help to point us to the right package with the above mentioned components/features

Comment: Don't get the question, none of your points are specific to postgresql.
1 4 and 5 are OS specific, trigger is a native function, GUI can be anything you want (search on google).

Comment: I suppose that for the GUI you'd want pgAdmin. For the server side, the latest stable version is 9.5.

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5: `yum install postgresql95-server` or http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload 3: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools  4: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Answer (score 0):

1. [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/)
2. [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)
3. [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/)
4. `pg_dump`, `pg_restore`, `psql`
5. [psql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_steps) lets you specify database (including remote) to connect to

All above works both windows and osX

Answer (score 0):

[EnterpriseDb](http://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) has free packages for postgres that include commonly used components like pgAdmin (a GUI). They have packages for both Windows and OS X but I would use homebrew instead for OS X. Homebrew is an OS X package manager. There's several tutorials for installing postgres via Homebrew. Here is [one](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/21/install-postgresql-on-mac-os-x-via-brew/).

You would install pgAdmin separately.

Installing via Homebrew is a little more complex but gives you more flexibility and capability.

If you're just starting out with postgres, the EnterpriseDB packages will be easier.